# webdav query Unauthorized on production server and authorized on testing server

Tags: c#, sharepoint, exchange-server, webdav

im trying to access my exchange inbox using webdav and it works from my testing server (windows 2003 64bit, contain MOSS instalation) and not from my production server (windows xp 32bit).

for authentication im using:

```
ICredentials credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
```

from my production server im getting:

```
The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
```

what can be the problem on my production server and how come it work on my testing server?

Answer (score 0):

MAybe because on the test machine you are also the admin. Try setting the credentials explicitly to a user account known to have the required access. DefaultCredentials might revert to say the Local Machine or Network Service account (although not sure about that).

Comment: you are right, im aslo the admin on the test server.  
how im sending the credentials of the current logon user?

Answer (score 0):

Check the local loopback check

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/896861